# Why frontend and server cannot connect through websocket after deployment

Tags: c#, angular, websocket, deployment, connection

After I deployed my app to amazon the connection between my frontend and server via websocket doesn't work. To be more precise, when I open the frontend form the amazon link and run the server on my computer it works, but when someone else tries to use the app from a different ip, messages don't come to the server.

Below, I put fragments of code that establish the connection.
Here is how I connect to the server in the frontend (Angular):

```
public openWebSocket(port : number){
this.webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.16:' + port.toString());

this.webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
  //console.log('Open: ', event);
}

this.webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
  //console.log('Received message: ', event);
  const msg : Message = JSON.parse(event.data);
  switch(msg.Type){ ...
```

and here is how I establsh a websocket on the server (C# console app):

```
public Server(int port)
    {
        //setup websocket
        _port = port;
        _webSocket = new WebSocketServer();

        RootConfig r = new RootConfig();
        ServerConfig s = new ServerConfig();
        s.Name = "SuperWebSocket";
        s.Ip = "Any";
        s.Port = port;
        s.Mode = SocketMode.Tcp;
        SuperSocket.SocketEngine.SocketServerFactory f = new SuperSocket.SocketEngine.SocketServerFactory();
        _webSocket.Setup(r, s, f);
        _webSocket.Listeners[0].EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.16"),port);

        _webSocket.NewSessionConnected += Connect;
        _webSocket.NewDataReceived += DataReceived;
        _webSocket.NewMessageReceived += MessageReceived;
        _webSocket.SessionClosed += SessionClosed; ...
```

Comment: You have to check the AWS firewall to connect other devices to your server machine

Comment: I did turn down the firewall and nothing improved.

Comment: most of the time the IP and port is not accessible in the cloud environments. To check this try access the web socket from any online tool you get more info

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. The problem is actually deeper than that because if I run the server on my computer, people from outside of my local net still cannot reach it, so I started to think I configure the sockets wrong.